# Rails Migration with Change_column says successful, but silently fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

My schema:

```
  create_table "location_hours", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My migration:

```
class ChangeLocationHourNulls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :location_hours, :start_at, :datetime, :null => :false
    change_column :location_hours, :end_at, :datetime, :null => :false
    change_column :location_hours, :location_id, :integer, :null => :false
  end
end
```

Rake Output:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
==  ChangeLocationHourNulls: migrating =======================================
-- change_column(:location_hours, :start_at, :datetime, {:null=>:false})
   -> 0.0008s
-- change_column(:location_hours, :end_at, :datetime, {:null=>:false})
   -> 0.0006s
-- change_column(:location_hours, :location_id, :integer, {:null=>:false})
   -> 0.0032s
==  ChangeLocationHourNulls: migrated (0.0067s) ==============================

   -> 0.0032s
==  ChangeLocationHourNulls: migrated (0.0067s) ==============================
```

When I check my schema file, it hasn't changed, and the database hasn't changed.  Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: Did you try without the `:null => :false` part !!

Comment: The purpose of this migrations is to not allow nulls.  They are currently nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollback the migration `ChangeLocationHourNulls`.

Then change your migration as below:

```
class ChangeLocationHourNulls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :location_hours, :start_at, :datetime, :null => false
    change_column :location_hours, :end_at, :datetime, :null => false
    change_column :location_hours, :location_id, :integer, :null => false
  end
end
```

Use `false` and not `:false`.

Run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Kirti advise should solve the issue but i just realized there is a better option in your case, since you just want to change Nullable option:

You could use [change_column_null](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null)  which works like this:

```
class ChangeLocationHourNulls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :location_hours, :start_at, false
    change_column_null :location_hours, :end_at, false
    change_column_null :location_hours, :location_id, false
  end
end
```